# Use different configuration for "ghci" and "stack ghci"

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-stack

I often use `ghci` for little calculations and `stack ghci` to work on my actual projects.

To make the first easier I have written a `.ghci` file with a lot of imported modules in it, but some of these modules aren't present in my stack project and I get nasty errors.

At the moment I use a alias `stackghci="stack ghci --ghci-options -ignore-dot-ghci"`, but then I have the default prompt again and so on..

Is there a way of specifying two `.ghci` files; one for stack and one for `ghci`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ghci supports the `--ghci-script` flag for specifying additional scripts to read at startup.

Docs for `--ghci-script`: [(link)](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghc-flag--ghci-script)